# Access log shows higher response time with inbuilt tomcat using Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, access-log

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.6.RELEASE which contains the Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.16. I am getting a very weird issue while working on performance tuning on one of our high performing APIs.

My resource endpoint e.g. /test takes 0 milliseconds to perform the execution of my request single call (which simple returns "SUCCESS" as a response) but when I see access log which is enabled using application.yml file shows a very higher response time i.e around 3-4 milliseconds. I am running the test locally on laptop which means there is no network latency.

tomcat access logs are enabled using

```
server:
port: 8082
context-path: /
tomcat:
accesslog:
# Enable access log:
enabled: true
# Directory in which log files are created. Can be relative to the tomcat base dir or absolute:
directory: /var/tmp/log
# Format pattern for access logs:
pattern: "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t '%r' %s %b %D"
# Log file name prefix
file-date-format: yyyy-MM-dd.HH
prefix: apache_access_
# Log file name suffix:
suffix: .log
```

**Environment**: Localhost [Laptop with Windows 7, i7, 16GB RAM).

Is there any issue on calculating response time (%D) in the apache access logs? I have no clue why it shows higher response time?

While looking at he source code of CoyoteAdapter.jave at org.apache.catalina.connector doesnt seems to be anything weird.
i.e. `time = System.currentTimeMillis() - req.getStartTime();`

Comment: When you say "resource endpoint e.g. /test takes 0 milliseconds", where is this measured? Only within the method of the resource endpoint? Then keep in mind, that Spring also has some logic to decide, which method to call for the request etc.

Comment: I measured /test resource endpoint using System.out after the start of the method and before return so that is within the method of the resource endpoint. Where can I see how much time is taken by Spring itself?

Comment: You can enable debug level logging (or even trace logging) or use a profiler to analyse your application.

Comment: We are also facing the same issue on latest spring boot version with embedded tomcat. Did anyone found the root cause for this issue ?